# I'm trying to shoot with vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, vector

I am currently writing a game in c++ with direct X and currently a vector to store draw all my sprites. I can't get bullets to work in the vector.
The bullet shoots but only one comes out when there should be 50

```
//this vector also contains all other sprites i have like my player and my score and other sprites 
///Draw is a class

vector<Draw*> chap;
vector<Draw*>::iterator it;
Draw *bullet = NULL;

///initialization of stuff
for (int i = 0; i < gt; i++)
{
    bullet = new Draw[gt];
    //this sets the x position and y position and other properties 
    bullet[i].setDraw(blet,0,0,.1,.1,0,64,64,1,0,1,color,0,0,90,0,0,false);
    chap.push_back(&bullet[i]);
}
//end initialization

///game loop
for (int i = 0; i < bell; i++)
{
    for (it = chap.begin(); it != chap.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->testShoot(&bullet[i], ME);
        ME->playerMove();
        monster1->move();
    }
}
///end loop there is other stuff in loop but doesn't effect anything

/// what i'm using 
void Draw::testShoot(Draw *sprite, Draw *sprite1)
{
    if ((int)timeGetTime() < timer + 100)return;
    timer = timeGetTime();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (Key_Down(DIK_SPACE))
        {
            if (!sprite[i].alive)
            {
                sprite[i].x = sprite1->x + sprite1->width / 4;
                sprite[i].y = sprite1->y + sprite1->height / 4;
                sprite[i].velx = 1;
                sprite[i].vely = 0;
                sprite[i].alive = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`bullet = new Draw[gt];` should go before the `for` loop, not inside it. Right now you're making a new array each iteration of the loop, which only has one populated element, and losing the previous ones you created when you overwrite the value in `bullet` each time round.

In other words, this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gt; i++)
{
    bullet = new Draw[gt];
    bullet[i].setDraw( ...
```

should be this:

```
bullet = new Draw[gt];
for (int i = 0; i < gt; i++)
{
     bullet[i].setDraw( ...
```

Comment: i forgot to put where the loop starts and where it ends, everything draws fine, there are no errors nothing breaks,

Comment: I didn't even notice that at all, I was looking in the wrong places to fix my problem.

Comment: Not to mention, depending on the size of `Draw` and `gt`, massive memory leaks :L